# Instagramm oauth from php

Tags: php, curl, oauth-2.0, instagram

I try to use instagramm oauth from PHP, in first I open oauth page, and get cookies(csrfmiddlewaretoken abnd mid) and parse in page csrfmiddlewaretoken hidden, and than i send it with my username and password on https://instagram.com/accounts/login/, but i get 304 error. Why?`

```
<?
    require_once 'inc.php';
        $redirect_uri =  "http://178.132.206.91/?viewer_id=".$_GET['viewer_id']."&auth_key=".$_GET['auth_key];

$link="https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=".INST_CLIENT."&redirect_uri=".$redirect_uri."&response_type=token";
//  $page=file_get_contents($link);

$ch = curl_init();
//Указываем URL, куда будем обращаться. Протокол https://
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, true);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_getinfo ( $ch );
$header = substr($page,0,curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE));
$body = substr($page,curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE));
preg_match_all("/Set-Cookie: (.*?)=(.*?);/i",$header,$res);
$cookie[$res[1][1]] = $res[2][1];
$cookie[$res[1][2]] = $res[2][2];
$cookies =  http_build_query($cookie, '', ';');
echo $page;
//echo $cookies;
curl_close($ch);
//echo $header;
    preg_match('#<input\s+type="hidden"\s+name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"\s+value="(.+?)".+?/>#si', $page, $match);
    $data['csrfmiddlewaretoken'] = $match[1];
    $data['username'] = "040819";
    $data['password'] = "040819";
    $datas = http_build_query($data, '', ';');
$ch = curl_init();

$authlink = "https://instagram.com/accounts/login/";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $authlink);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookies); 
print_r($cookies);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datas); 
$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_getinfo($ch);
$header = substr($page,0,curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE));
$body = substr($page,curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE));
    echo $page;

    echo $csr;
?>`
```

Comment: 304 is not an error. 4xx and 5xx statuses are errors.

Comment: Ok. I understand but it must do riderect on riderect uri, but i get 304(